# How do I get results unique to a specific value in a table

Tags: mysql

Terribly worded question I'm sure, but I couldn't think of a better way to phrase it. Here's the idea, assume I have a table that looks like this:

```
id, status, orgId
123, green, 1
234, green, 1
345, blue,  1
456, blue,  2
567, blue,  2
789, red,   3
890, green, 3
```

I'm looking to get a list of all orgId's where the statuses of all id's for an orgId are blue. Given this criteria that query would result in "2" given the above table.

Forgive me if this is something fairly easy, but my depth of knowledge with SQL is fairly shallow. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you're going to want to use distinct because you're only looking for one of each answer, and you need to have a `WHERE` clause that only gets where the status is blue.

```
SELECT
    find.id
FROM (
    SELECT
        DISTINCT(orgId) AS id
    FROM
        my_table item
    WHERE
        item.status = 'blue') find
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            my_table verify
        WHERE
            verify.orgId = find.id
        AND
            verify.status != 'blue')
```

Comment: Hi Kyle, thanks for the help! I think this has me going in the right direction, but it looks like there might be a piece missing. This query will return 1 _and_ 2. I'm looking for a query that would only return 2 given the above table. (Only orgId's whose id's are all set to 'blue')

Comment: Woohoo! Thanks Kyle I appreciate it. It would've taken me quite some time to sort through that on my own. Very happy, thanks. Wish I could upvote you, but sadly I'm too new here. :(

Comment: Glad to help. Good luck on future endeavors!